# How to read a text file that contains paths to other text files that need read powershell

Tags: powershell, file, text

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will:

1. Read a text file (Paths.txt) that contains paths (path1, path2,..).
2. For each path, I want to read it's content and look for specific text (such as "UNDER LINE").

   - If it is found, add content of another file (Add.txt) under this area.
   - If not, add this specific text ("UNDER LINE") to the file and the content of the file (Add.txt)

---

Edit from Redd:

As promised we are woking this to together.

current Code from comments:

```
$p = C:\user\paths.txt 
$paths = get-content $p
```

Rewrite:

```
$paths = Get-Content "C:\user\paths.txt"
```

Now the goal is to loop for every line. Here you'd use an ForEach-Loop.

```
ForEach($path in $paths){
    Write-Host $path
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: not much I've tried using get-content which will get the content of paths.txt but as far as opening those paths inside that text file and opening path1.txt path2.txt haven't figured out best way to do that so it doesn't combine them both into one line.

Comment: Well let's work this out toghter untill we have the first part of code to post or?
So we start with reading the content of paths.txt with ```Get-Content```
After that we want to loop over every line (line -eq path) and use ```Get-conten``` on that or?

Comment: Would we want to use foreach($line in $paths)?

I have this 
$p = C:\user\paths.txt
$paths = get-content $p

Comment: @DevinLathsaw I added you code above. please user the @ symbol because I didn't see your comment ^^

Comment: @A guest who's called Redd sorry about that. Okay so I have it set up that way, is there a issue with though setting the txt file as a variable like i did above see you rewrote that. It does print off the lines from the text file....

Answer (score 0):

So you have this so far..

```
$paths = Get-Content "C:\user\paths.txt"
ForEach($path in $paths){
    Write-Host $path
}
```

Next you will need to `Get-Content $path` within the first `ForEach` loop, then, loop through the contents of that file by using another `ForEach` loop inside the first loop. Then add `If` statements to check if the line has "UNDER LINE" within that line.

There are other ways of getting this done, but this is an easy way that is easy to read. Sorry I couldn't walk you through it because I can't comment since I don't have enough rep yet. But I commented the code below and hopefully you can see what I am doing. If this isn't what you were trying to do or if you have any questions just let me know!

```
$paths = Get-Content "C:\Users\paths.txt"
# Loop through paths.txt for each path

ForEach($path in $paths){
    # Store the content of $path
    $OriginalFile = Get-Content $path

    # List for creating the new updated/modified file
    [String[]]$ModifiedFile = @()

    # Loop through each line of the Original file
    ForEach($line in $OriginalFile){

        # Check the line if "UNDER LINE" is on that line
        if($line -like "*UNDER LINE*"){

            # Add the current line from the Original file to the new file
            $ModifiedFile += $line

            # Add the content of Add.txt (Update the path for the Add.txt)
            $ModifiedFile += Get-Content ".\Add.txt"
        }
        # If the line from the Original file doesn't contain "UNDER LINE"
        else {

            # Add "UNDER LINE" to the new file
            $ModifiedFile += "UNDER LINE"

            # Add the content of Add.txt (Update the path for the Add.txt)
            $ModifiedFile += Get-Content ".\Add.txt"
        }
    }

    # This will overwrite $path file with the modified version.
    # For testing purposes change $path to a new file name to verify output txt file is correct.
    Set-Content $path $ModifiedFile
}
```